# Cannot convert value of type error Swift

Tags: swift

I'm following a [tutorial](http://shrikar.com/ios-swift-development-step-counter-app-using-pedometer-data/) on making a simple pedometer app, and I'm getting the following error

> Cannot convert value of type '(CMPedometerData!, _) -> Void' to
>   expected argument type 'CMPedometerHandler' (aka
>   '(Optional, Optional) -> ()')

on these lines of code:

```
if(CMPedometer.isStepCountingAvailable()){
                   let fromDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: -86400 * 7)
                   self.pedoMeter.queryPedometerDataFromDate(fromDate, toDate: NSDate()) { (data : CMPedometerData!, error) -> Void in
                       print(data)
                       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                           if(error == nil){
                               self.steps.text = "\(data.numberOfSteps)"
                           }
                       })
                   }
                   self.pedoMeter.startPedometerUpdatesFromDate(midnightOfToday) { (data: CMPedometerData!, error) -> Void in
                       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                           if(error == nil){
                               self.steps.text = "\(data.numberOfSteps)"
                           }
                       })
                   }
               }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler’s telling you that the handler you’re providing is of the wrong type—you have the first parameter as an implicitly-unwrapped optional rather than an optional (it has a `!` rather than a `?`), and the second parameter has no type at all. In other words, the bits that look like this:

```
(data : CMPedometerData!, error) -> Void
```

…should look like this instead:

```
(data : CMPedometerData?, error: NSError?) -> Void
```